# Redis service failed to start on Windows 7

Tags: .net, redis, memorycache, servicestack.redis

I am exploring in memory caching on my win 7 dev box with .NET 4.5, VS2013 with update 4 and have shortlisted Redis for the same. I have downloaded ver 2.8.19 from [here](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases) and have followed the instructions to install the service which it does without any problem. However when I try to start the service I get a generic message:

> [3464] 28 Apr 00:35:11.890 # Redis service failed to start.

I have enabled logging to a text file as well as to the event viewer. Nothing is reported in the text file and the event viewer, I only see redis service started followed by Redis service stopped. There is no other information as to why this is failing. Have I missed any step?

Comment: do you have a log path in your .conf? if so: what does the log output say? is there anything in the event log?

Comment: Yes I do. The logs only mention the details of service installation. Not when I attempt to start the service. I just get the generic message above. Logging is set to debug mode.

Comment: Redis doesn't register its own handle in the event log but in the system log I see two entries back to back 1.The Redis service entered the running state. 2.The Redis service entered the stopped state.

Answer (score 2):

add below configuration in C:\Program Files\Redis\redis.windows-service.conf file

maxheap 128m

maxmemory 64m

no idea why ms doesn't provide default value in this file :)
http://njun.blog.cndevel.com/software/redis-user-guide